# Как реализовать цикл в Ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, циклы

Как реализовать такой цикл на ассемблере:

```
FOR I:=1 TO 9 DO IF X[I] < 0 THEN AL:=AL+1
```

Вот что имею, может кто подскажет, что не так или что добавить, чего то не хватает (мне так кажется), а чего не могу понять (не судите строго)

```
MOV   SI,1     
MOV   CX,9
M1: MOV  AL,ARRAY_X[SI]
    CMP  AL,0
    JS M2
    INC SI   
M2: inc  AL
    LOOP M1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С чего стоит начать - переписать цикл через `while`, с разбивкой на блоки, лучше сразу с именами регистров вместо имен переменных:

```
al := 0
di := 1
while di <= 9 do
    if x[di] < 0
        al := al + 1
    end if
    di := di + 1
end while
```

Дальше можно просто построчно переводить на ассемблер:

```
    mov al, 0
    mov di, 1
start_while:
    ; for - это все-таки цикл с предусловием, поэтому проверяем условие при входе в цикл
    cmp di, 9
    jg end_while  
    cmp array_x[di], 0  ; не обязательно куда-то перезаписывать, чтобы сравнить
    jae end_if  ; jump if above or equal - инвертированное условие, above - сравнение с учетом знака числа
    inc al
end_if:
    inc di
    jmp start_while
end_while:
    ...

array_x db 10 dup ?
```

Можно реализовать и через `loop`, но мне лично не нравится, что в этом случае резервируется регистр `cx` на счетчик цикла, получится что в цикле будет два счетчика - `cx` и `di`, один для отсчета итераций, другой для индексирования. Как-то слишком расточительно.